# Dynamic path (Date) not getting Updated in snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, external-tables

I have created external table in snowflake and it should refresh if data is there in s3.

my S3 bucket URL is  :

```
s3://compnay_bucket/pitc/2022-03-25/Investor
```

In the above URL date  should be dynamic and I have set the pattern as :

```
set investor_pattern = '\.*/'||to_char(current_date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'\/Investor/'||'\.*';
```

My External DDL is

```
create or replace external table PITCHBOOK_DEV.PB_Investor 
(
    InvestorID varchar(60) as ( $1:InvestorID::varchar ),
  InvestorName varchar(60) as ( $1:InvestorName::varchar )

)
with location = @compa/pitc/
file_format = company_parquet
pattern=$investor_pattern
aws_sns_topic='arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:5:snowfla'
auto_refresh = true
```

So far tried :

i) When I execute "show external table PITCHBOOK_DEV.PB_Investor" command. I can see SNS notification being kicked off. SO there Is NO ISSUE with SNS.

ii) when I do an ls on stage with today's date it is returning me files.

**if I execute "investor_pattern"  and "create table..", I am able to see today's data. This should happen dynamically.**

Please let me know what should be changed here.?

Comment: If your external table DDL actually has "pattern=$investor_pattern" then that won't work as "$investor_pattern" only has a value during the lifetime of any session you set it in. So it may work during the session when you gave this parameter a value and created the table - but anyone else querying the table (or you querying the table in a different session without setting the variable) won't see any data

Comment: Correct it is not working, what should I do?

Comment: Try setting the pattern directly in the DDL rather than via a variable? e.g. pattern= '\.*/'||to_char(current_date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'\/Investor/'||'\.*'

Comment: no it is giving and error 
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 12 at position 14 unexpected '||'.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you can’t have dynamic patterns. You could try creating n external table with all the data and then a view on top of it that filters on the current date

Comment: can i keep all this in a stored procedure and schedule it?